# Fastest way to get user's latest 20 friend checkins?

Tags: facebook, performance, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'd like to get the current users 20 latest friend's checkins.  I did the following FQL query which works, but is very slow (~10 seconds):

```
SELECT checkin_id
FROM checkin
WHERE author_uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 0,20
```

I did notice that if I put a time filter it comes back much faster, but it won't guarantee I get back the last 20 checkins.

```
SELECT checkin_id
FROM checkin
WHERE timestamp > 1317252997
AND author_uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
LIMIT 0,20
```

Does anyone have any advice on speeding this up or a faster way to do this?  Should I be looking at the stream table perhaps?  I also didn't see an obvious way to get this with the graph api.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Great question (upvoted it for you), but I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the time saving? If big enough, you could do incremental search?